# How to get a Web Service to use a Fixed Port Number When Using the Visual Studio Development Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an asp.net website and a windows form application.

My Webservice's Location is : http://localhost:12312/MyWebSiteFolder/WSFile.asmx

Problem is : the port number keeps changing, if I reopen the solution, its going to change to something else:

http://localhost:11122/MyWebSiteFolder/WSFile.asmx

Is there a way so I won't have to update the location of the file in my windows form application everytime I reopen the website's solution?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(assuming Visual Studio 2010)

Under the Web tab of the properties for the project, change the "Auto-assign Port" option to "Specific port" and enter the port you want to always use.
[image]

Alternately, if possible, you can choose the option to use your local IIS server.

**Update**:

If you're using a "Web Site" project instead of "Web Application," the setting is located in the properties *window* of the project instead of the properties *dialog*.  Note the "Use dynamic ports" option here:
[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I know properties exist in windows form but I can't seem to find it in my website

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: The UI I'm showing is for a "Web Application" project; is your project a "Web Site"?

Comment: See my update; that option is still available, just elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

How does your web application look on the Solution explorer - does it show

```
<drive>:\<some directory>
```

or 
does it show the name of your web application with no path.
or
does it show `http:/// <something>`

In case 1 you should be able to see properties. But you wont get it for the rest

Comment: i mean to type &lt;drive&gt;:\&lt;directory name&gt;