# How to set fixed port in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-express

I do not know if its a limitation of VSE 2012 or if I am looking at it incorrectly but I cannot for the life of me find the option to disable the dynamic port of my web service. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17631024/properties.jpg) is what I am seeing under my project properties and [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17631024/propertypage.jpg) is the property page. According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738451/how-to-get-a-web-service-to-use-a-fixed-port-number-when-using-the-visual-studio) I should be getting very different options. Any ideas? (Screens would be more convenient but alas, I do not have the rep yet)

Comment: The problem is not getting to the properties, I linked to my screens in the original question. The problem I have is it is extremely limited and missing the options I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently a shortcoming of the VS Web Express software. I had to dig deep and asked my professor. Time wasted but lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

Steps are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.ASPX).

> **To specify a port for a Web application project that uses IIS Express**
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the application and
>      then select Properties. Click the Web tab.
> 2. In the Servers section, under Use Local IIS Web server, in the
>      Project URL box change the port number.
> 3. To the right of the Project URL box, click Create Virtual Directory,
>      and then click OK.
> 4. In the File menu, click Save Selected Items.
> 5. To verify the change, press CTRL+F5 to run the project.
>
> The new port number appears in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: I included links to my screens to make it a little clearer, but I do not have a 'web' tab